# Why is 'n' parameter of snprintf ignored?

Tags: string

I have found that the `n` parameter of `snprintf()` seems to be ignored in my code.

```
char asdf[10];
Serial1.println(snprintf(asdf, 2, "hello"));
```

This prints 5 when I would expect it to print 2. What is happening?

Comment: Does the variable `asdf` contain "hello" or "h"? If it contains "h" then the parameter has not been ignored.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

snprintf() will not write more than <size> (snprintf's 2d argument) characters to your buffer, but it does count (and discard the extra) characters it would have written, had there been space enough, and that is the number it returns. Yeah, it can be confusing!

See this [snprintf() reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/).

Comment: It would be helpful because you could `snprintf` to a very small buffer, note the number returned, then `malloc` a buffer of the appropriate size, and do it again. That way you know how many bytes to allocate.

Comment: @NickGammon: Or you can `snprintf` to no buffer whatsoever (a null destination pointer is explicitly described as a valid argument for the destlength==0 case) when measuring the length.

Comment: Indeed. That is also done in Windows text output routines to measure how much space some text in some font would occupy, without actually drawing it.

Answer (score 2):

A test sketch for the Arduino Uno:

```
char buffer[10];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int n = snprintf(buffer, 2, "hello");
  Serial.println(n);
  Serial.println(buffer);
}

void loop() {
}
```

As @JRobert wrote, the "would have" is the key. As far as I know only the [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) and the [vsnprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsnprintf/) return a "would have" number.

I think the reason is to be able to tell if the string was truncated. Suppose the 'size' parameter is 25 and the format string is very long, then the return value can be tested against 25. If the return value was 26 (the "would have" number of bytes), then the string was truncated.
This information was not possible to retrieve when the "would have" number was not available.

Answer (score 2):

For completion, the man page for [`fprintf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3p.html) states:

> The snprintf() function shall be equivalent to sprintf(), with the
>   addition of the n argument which states the size of the buffer
>   referred to by s.  If n is zero, nothing shall be written and s may
>   be a null pointer. Otherwise, output bytes beyond the n‐1st shall be
>   discarded instead of being written to the array, and a null byte is
>   written at the end of the bytes actually written into the array.

and, more relevant:

> Upon successful completion, the snprintf() function shall return the
>          number of bytes that would be written to s had n been sufficiently
>          large excluding the terminating null byte.